# C++-WinRT's com_ptr reset?

Tags: directx-11, c++-winrt

I am attempting to port the DirectX11/XAML UWP template over to a C++-WinRT version... where EVERYTHING is done via C++-WinRT and I can turn off CX.

I'm currently stuck on how to `ResizeBuffers` on the swapchain.  I keep getting the error that says I haven't released all of the buffer references.  If I comment out anything to do with resizing buffers and just hardcode in a size, the app works.  So... I am probably doing something wrong.

I believe it has to do with the new `winrt::com_ptr`.  There is no `Reset` method like on the WRL ComPtr.  I have set them to `nullptr` just like in the original C++/CX templates, but that doesn't seem to be enough.

Other things I've had to do that may have an affect on what's going on:

1. The DeviceResources class is now a C++/WinRT class that I am creating by default in all of the other classes (SampleScene3DRenderer, DirectXPage, & Main) using the nullptr_t parameter.  That way, I can create it in the DirectXPage, pass in the swapChainPanel reference, then pass this one DeviceResources instance to all of the other classes I create.
2. There's one spot in the DirectX initialization where you have to pass in a `**IUnknown`.  The docs for C++/WinRT mention using a function called `winrt::get_unknown` to return an `*IUnknown`.  I couldn't get it to work for the following `DWriteCreateFactory` method so I tried it this way:

   ```
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
       DWriteCreateFactory(
          DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED,
          __uuidof(IDWriteFactory3),
          reinterpret_cast<::IUnknown**>(m_dwriteFactory.put())
       )
   );
   ```

I'm not sure what else to do.  Only the swapchain resizing doesn't work.  I'm doing this on PC (not windows phone).

Comment: RE: 1 - You don't have to stop using ``Microsoft::WRL:ComPtr`` to use C++/WinRT. It builds just fine without ``/ZW``. You can use ``winrt::com_ptr`` instead, but it has nothing to do with removing ``/ZW``.  RE: 2 - Have you tried using ``static_cast<::IUnknown*>(winrt::get_abi(window))``?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn: Shouldn't this be [winrt::put_abi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/put-abi) here?

Comment: Ah, I thought so... I was just in namespace hell for a while with the ambiguous Windows namespace error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `DWriteCreateFactory` call using `winrt::com_ptr<T>` and the `put` member above is correct. Also using `nullptr` assignment is the correct way to reset a `com_ptr<T>`.

```cpp
com_ptr<IUnknown> ptr = ...

assert(ptr);
ptr = nullptr;
assert(!ptr);
```

You can also use `winrt::check_hresult` rather than `ThrowIfFailed` if you wish to be consistent with how C++/WinRT reports errors. Here's a simple DirectX example written entirely with C++/WinRT:

https://github.com/kennykerr/cppwinrt/blob/master/Store/Direct2D/App.cpp

Comment: Thanks, I will look over that sample... I didn't know this one existed.

Comment: Funny, I'm just in the process of going through your old Plural Sight courses on COM (well done by the way).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Now, it works after I moved my include for `unknwn.h` to before all of the `winrt` includes.

```
// pch.h
#pragma once

#include <unknwn.h>
#include <winrt/windows.globalization.datetimeformatting.h>
#include <winrt/windows.web.syndication.h>



#include <winrt/windows.foundation.collections.h>
#include <winrt/windows.foundation.numerics.h>


#include <winrt/windows.graphics.display.h>


#include <winrt/windows.applicationmodel.h>
#include <winrt/windows.applicationmodel.activation.h>
#include <winrt/windows.applicationmodel.core.h>


#include <winrt/windows.ui.h>
// #include <winrt/Windows.ui.core.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Core.h>
#include <winrt/windows.ui.composition.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <d2d1_1.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3d11_2.h>
#include <d3d12.h>
#include <dxgi1_2.h>
```